# C - Remove Duplicate Results in Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion

I have to create a recursive function that tells you the number of ways a number of cents can be made into change. (Using quarters, dimes nickels, and pennies).

So far, I have a recursive function that does that, however it counts the same combination more than once, so the number is too big. How do I remove the duplicate combinations?

Code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
//Prototypes
int coins(int);

int main(void){
    //Declarations
    int num;

    //Get user input
    printf("Enter an amount of change in cents: ");
    scanf("%d", &num); //Change to fgets

    //Call function
    printf("There are %d ways to make change for %d cents.\n", (coins(num)), num);
}

int coins(int amt){
    //Declarations
    int ways=0;

    //Base Case
    if(amt == 0){
        return 1;
    }

    //int ways=0; More efficient after base case.

    if(amt >= 1){
        ways+=coins(amt-1);
    }
    if(amt >= 5){
        ways+=coins(amt-5);
    }
    if(amt >= 10){
        ways+=coins(amt-10);
    }
    if(amt >= 25){
        ways+=coins(amt-25);
    }

    return ways;
}
```

Example:

Input: 17 (cents)

Output: 80 ways
**Output should be 6

Comment: What are duplicates? Seems to me that there is more than 6 ways of making 17 (cents)

Comment: @PeCosta A duplicate for example: 1 penny 1 nickel vs 1 nickel 1 penny. or in my case I believe the function is counting the same combination more than once. And there should only be 6 ways to make 17.

Comment: Oh you don't have 2 cents ok!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int coins(int, int);

int main(void){
    int num;

    printf("Enter an amount of change in cents: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("There are %d ways to make change for %d cents.\n", coins(num, 0), num);
    return 0;
}

int coins(int amt, int kind){
    static int kinds[4] = {25, 10, 5, 1};
    int ways=0, i, n;

    if(kinds[kind] == 1)//always divisible
        return 1;

    n = amt / kinds[kind];
    for(i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
        ways+=coins(amt-kinds[kind]*i, kind + 1);

    return ways;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the for loop do? I understand it I'm just having trouble putting it into words?

Comment: Loop to calculate in each case the number of coins that can be used at that point.

Comment: So, it starts at largest denomination, checks the number of coins that can be used at that point, and goes until kind[3] is reached. Correct?